# Simulating struct static field behaviour in Rust / when multiple instances have to access same object

Tags: rust

I have a problem that I want to solve in Rust that would be solved by simply using static fields in a struct, but Rust does not permit this.

Suppose I want to have multiple sockets, so I define a struct called `Socket`:

```
pub struct Socket {

}
```

but each socket will use the same `Wire` to send the packets. In C++, I'd have something like this:

```
struct Socket {
    static Wire wire;
}
```

and simply every socket can share the same `Wire`.

The obvious solution would be to pass the same `Wire` to every new `Socket` in the constructor:

```
pub struct Socket {
    pub fn new(wire: SomeSharedRefType) {
    //...
    }
}
```

but there's a particular reason I don't want to do this. I want to create new Rust `Socket` objects from C++. While it's possible to create the unique Rust `Wire` from C++ and pass it to every C++ call of `Socket::new`, I want to avoid that because it's unsafe and I want to Rust to be able to manage the lifetime of almost everything. I don't want C++ to take this responsibility.

If you think I'm trying to solve an unnecessary problem, please tell me what would be a good solution, but also tell me if it's possible to simulate a static field on Rust by some technique, because I want to learn.

Comment: I'm confused, if you want a static variable why not just make a [static](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html) variable?

Comment: @kmdreko I thought I couldnt put them inside structs

Comment: You can’t, but who cares? Rust scoping is different from C++ but is generally less leaky.

Comment: @mcarton oh right. But now I have another problem: I can't initialize simple things like hashmap. Seems like only simple static types are allowed? (unless using the `lazy_static` crate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create new Rust Socket objects from C++. While it's possible to create the unique Rust Wire from C++ and pass it to every C++ call of Socket::new, I want to avoid that because it's unsafe and I want to Rust to be able to manage the lifetime of almost everything. I don't want C++ to take this responsibility.

I'm not sure what difference it makes. The C++ side has to call a socket creation factory of some sort, why can't it pass an opaque wire, possibly alongside the other parameters?

> also tell me if it's possible to simulate a static field on Rust by some technique, because I want to learn.

Static variables. Static members are stored on the class, Rust doesn't have classes to store them in, so it doesn't have static members.

Comment: The more objects I create in C++ to pass to Rust, the more fragile the Rust side gets, because if I destruct the object on the C++ side, the Rust side will access invalid data. So the desired way would be to create only the sockets through C++, but the objects inside each Socket, as `Wire` and possibly others, are managed totally by Rust. Then I can freely destruct things in C++ as there are no nested cpp-created Rust objects

Comment: There are no objects to "create in C++". The C++ asks Rust for a wire object and passes *that* when it then asks for sockets.

Comment: "So the desired way would be to create only the sockets through C++" if sockets are rust types they need to be created on the rust side. Your question is even more bonkers if you think you could have C++ just create a non-c++ socket instance and have the vtable be correctly setup (which would be a requirement for static members to work).